# Nebular radio button cursor change on hover

Tags: html, angular, radio-button, hover, nebular

In Nebular, the pointer by default doesn't change on hovering above `nb-radio`. I need to implement it and I tried it by including the label within a `span` tag and setting `pointer-events` to auto but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a workaround for it?

**app.component.html**

```
<nb-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
    <nb-radio *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
        <span style="pointer-events: auto;">{{option.label}}</span>
    </nb-radio>
</nb-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the CSS `cursor` property.

Example:

```
nb-radio {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```